# Network programming with ruby

Tags: ruby, networking

My homework is to use ruby to build a simple spider(or crawler).
In ruby,to fetch web page what build-in moduel should I use?
I known python has a urllib moduel!

Comment: ruby has a uri module, we call modules gems in ruby.
but you should put in some research before asking questions here if you want help. Otherwise people will just down vote you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) module or search for something that builds on top of it.

Comment: thx,guys.I will do some research next time.Keep that im mind,huh?!

Comment: @castiel: I looked this up on google in about 30 seconds, no reason you can't do the same.  And questions like these don't really add particularly valuable content to the site.